# Using fuzziness attribute in C# Nest

Tags: c#, lucene, elasticsearch, nest

We are using a query with a query string build through NEST in C# to make searches against Elastic Search. It seems the fuzziness property that uses a discrete value 0,1, or 2 is supported in Elastic Search but not in NEST which supports instead the fuzzy_min_sim old style with the double value between 0 and 1. Is there a way to use the new fuzziness property in NEST or should we transform the integer value to the double value ourselves and use the fuzzy_min_sim attribute?

This is an example of a query we would use:

```
{
  "size": 500,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "oracle",
      "fields": [
        "contentsWord"
      ],
      "default_operator": "and",
      "fuzzy_prefix_length": 1,
      "fuzzy_min_sim": 0.2,
      "phrase_slop": 0.0
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<em>"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</em>"
    ],
    "fragment_size": 500000,
    "fields": {
      "contentsWord": {}
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "nameWord"
  ]
```

}

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like NEST supports the fuzziness option for query string queries yet.  One approach you could try for now is using the [fuzzy operator](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_fuzziness) in the query string itself.